# JavaScript и Raphaël Подключение

Tags: raphael, веб-программирование, jquery, javascript, include

Нужно подключить библиотеку рафаель к ява-скрипту, у меня есть

- index.html
- core.js
- style.css <br><br>
  Мне нужна библиотека со своими функциями в файле core.js, а в интернете нашел подключение только к html-странице...
  p.s в core.js только javascript код )
  Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://requirejs.org/